# How to ignore non integer input and continue taking input

Tags: java, input, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I am trying to ignore any non-integer input (e.g. r, $, £) and continue taking input until there is an integer input. Any help is appreciated.

```
    while (input.hasNextInt()){

    int column = input.nextInt();
    if (column < 0 || column > 6){
      errorWrongInput();
      continue;
    } 
    if(placeCounter(board,column,player)) {
      if (hasWon(board)){
          System.out.println ("Player " +player+ " wins");
          printBoard(board);
          return;
      }
      player = playerTurn(player);
    }
  printBoard(board); // print the board
  }
}
```

Comment: any non int input will throw an exception, what more do you need?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Ive started programming 3 weeks ago and Im not quite sure where to include the try and catch blocks within this code. ive tried some but they caused errors

Comment: what try and catch blocks? you can't enter any non-numerical data. You shouldn't go for try-catch blocks. If you have to be able to enter non-numerical data and handle that by saying "invalid input", use conditional statements instead

Comment: Hi @Stultuske I tried it but not quite sure where In the code I should include it.

Comment: where you should include what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully helps.. if not, do comment where it missed..

```
while (input.hasNext()){ // use hasNext instead of hasNextInt
try{
    int column = input.nextInt();
    if (column < 0 || column > 6){
      errorWrongInput();
      continue;
    } 
} //Brackets required to close try
catch (InputMismatchException ex){ //catch Exception here for non integer input
            input.next(); // do a next() here
            continue;
        }
    if(placeCounter(board,column,player)) {
      if (hasWon(board)){
      System.out.println ("Player " +player+ " wins");
      printBoard(board);
      return;
      }
      player = playerTurn(player);
    }
  printBoard(board); // print the board
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi it gives me some error:   MyConnectFour.java:32: error: 'catch' without 'try'
catch (InputMismatchException ex){ //catch Exception here for non integer input
^
MyConnectFour.java:26: error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations
try{
^

Comment: @Aditya throwing Exceptions if it can be easily handled with a single conditional statement is not exactly a good solution

Comment: @Stultuske I don't think there are much option for the user in this situation since Scanner is used. Scanner doesn't have the option of nextChar.

Comment: @Han : a simple next or nextLine and a regex pattern match will go a very far way.